# escape special character json angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Is there a built in way to escape json characters in angular (4)

here's my returned json -  I want to remove the `&nbsp;` return symbols etc. A regex feels a bit hacky, prefer to use native / built in function.

**EDIT:** The `{{ val }}` expression are deliberate and I want to keep these.

[image]

```
"values": [
    "<p>value&nbsp;{{ val }}&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p><strong>value2 {{ val2 }}</strong></p>\n"
]
```

Comment: can you post your JSON here.?

Comment: @MohitJain added JSON

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any inbuilt method which will resolve your problem. but as of now, you can stringify it and then just use replace,
example :

```
let jsonData  = {"values" : [    "<p>value&nbsp;{{ val }}&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p>
<strong>value2 {{ val2 }}</strong></p>\n"]}
 console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData).replace("&nbsp;",''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regex, because those HTML characters are variable. But if you only want to remove the `&nbsp;`, simply do

```
values = values.replace('&nbsp;', '');
```

For all characters :

```
values = values.replace(new RegExp(/&[\w]{4};/, 'g', ''))
```